# Common_schema function get_option not found after installation

Tags: mysql

So I've installed common_schema to my mysql server and tried to do action with get_option function.

My SQL:

```
SELECT *, ((get_option("program_invested_details", "received") * 100) / get_option("program_invested_details", "invested")) AS PERCENT_TOTAL FROM hp_programs_list WHERE program_add_status = 4 AND program_status = 1 ORDER BY PERCENT_TOTAL DESC
```

but it seems, that get_option function doesn't work, becouse I got this error:

> FUNCTION hyips_database.get_option does not exist

my DB structure:

[image: db structure]

Comment: Try: `SELECT *, ((common_schema.get_option("...`.

Comment: @wchiquito didn't worked...

Comment: What error you get? Remember `common_schema` is a different schema. `get_option ` not exist in `hyips_database`.

Comment: `FUNCTION common_schema.get_option does not exist` this is the error after code changing

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT * FROM common_schema.status`?

Comment: `Table 'common_schema.status' doesn't exist` response

Comment: also, common_schema structure: http://prntscr.com/6teij7

Comment: Check your installation, `common_schema` seems not installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A little test:

```sql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.                                             Your MySQL connection id is 8                                                                         
Server version: 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 (Ubuntu)                                                      Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| common_schema      |
| mydb               |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+                                                          
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `common_schema`.`status`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                       project_name: common_schema
                            version: 2.2
                           revision: 523
                       install_time: 2015-01-01 00:00:01
                    install_success: 1
          base_components_installed: 1
 innodb_plugin_components_installed: 1
percona_server_components_installed: 0
              install_mysql_version: 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
                   install_sql_mode: NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `test`;
Database changed

mysql> SELECT `get_option`('{name: "Wallace", num_children: 0, "pet": Gromit}', 'pet') `result`;
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION test.get_option does not exist

mysql> SELECT `common_schema`.`get_option`('{name: "Wallace", num_children: 0, "pet": Gromit}', 'pet') `result`;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| Gromit |
+--------+                                                          
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```